# Selenium Webdriver- to select a Dropdown value-It takes Longer duration of time

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I have inspect a value from a dropdown. But the dropdown is not in select class,its under `ul->li`. So Dropdown has list of values under `<li>`.I have get all the list of elements By using List of WebElements<> and tried to click an element. 
Its Working fine for other dropdown but,Its Taking 1min ( a long duration) to click an element(value) from the dropdown.Please suggest me the solution to sort out the problem.

The method which I used is:

```
List<WebElement> Modules=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='t-popup t-group']/ul/li")); 
for ( WebElement we: Modules) { //System.out.println(we.getText());
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if ( we.getText().contains(Attribute)) { 
      we.click(); 
    } 
    waitgen(1000); 
}
```

Comment: Can post your code & html snippet of that ?

Comment: The method which i used is:List<WebElement> Modules=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='t-popup t-group']/ul/li"));
  
   for ( WebElement we: Modules)
   {  //System.out.println(we.getText());
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    if ( we.getText().contains(Attribute))
    {
     we.click();
    }
    waitgen(1000);
   
   }

Comment: <div class="t-popup t-group" style="display: block; height: 200px; >
<ul class="t-reset">
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">BIO</li>
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">CompanyName</li>
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">ExceptionCode</li>
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">Flag</li>
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">HtmlPath</li>
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">KeywordStatus</li>
<li class="t-item" unselectable="on">LINKCount</li>
</ul>

Comment: What does `waitgen` do? If it waits, then that's the cause of the one minute delay. Clicking directly on the `Select` element as in @Santoshsarma's answer will avoid the loop; not calling `waitgen` will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you iteration through loop for clicking on specified element?

Try with below logic to click on specified element.

```
//Clicking on div
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.t-popup.t-group")).click();
//clicking on li based on text
String attribute="HtmlPath";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='t-popup t-group']//li[text()='"+attribute+"']")).click();
```